# Error when building with vtk: "fatal error: tbb/atomic.h file not found"

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

I'm working on a c++ program that uses opencv and vtk. These are the includes in my main file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkDirectory.h>
```

I run the following commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

The files successfully generate but then when I run `make`, I get this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target MyProject
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/MyProject.cpp.o
In file included from [...]/MyProject.cpp:33:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtkSmartPointer.h:26:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtkSmartPointerBase.h:30:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtkObjectBase.h:54:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtkAtomicTypes.h:18:
/usr/local/include/vtkAtomic.h:28:10: fatal error: 'tbb/atomic.h' file not found
#include <tbb/atomic.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/MyProject.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3 FATAL_ERROR)
project( MyProject )

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
if (NOT VTK_FOUND)
  message("Skipping MyProject: ${VTK_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE}")
  return ()
else()
  include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
  add_executable(MyProject MyProject.cpp )
  target_link_libraries(MyProject ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
  target_link_libraries(MyProject ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif()
message (STATUS "VTK_VERSION: ${VTK_VERSION}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I wondered if tbb was not installed and discovered it was not linked:

```
$ brew install tbb
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: tbb 2020_U0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link tbb` to link this version.
```

Resolved by running `brew link tbb`